bash: grep latest file in a directory over ssh
I have a code where I can grep a very specific file over ssh:
ssh ${username}@${host} << -EOF
grep -n ${text} ${filename}
EOF

which will output the desired text. However, now I want to do the same thing, but only for the latest file in a directory. I have tried several different options including:
ssh ${username}@${host} "ls -t ${directory} | head -n 1" | xargs grep "${text}"

ssh ${username}@${host} << -EOF
grep -n ${text} `ls ${directory} | head -n1`
EOF

But it seems to try to find the latest file (and, thus, directory) on my local machine and not over ssh. What is missing here?

What is the latest file? The file with the most recent modification time (this is suggested by your use of -t, but better saying it explicitly)? The file with name highest in sorting order? The file last in directory order? Another point to consider: Can the filenames contain newline characters?

it would be the latest modified file in the directory. . And the filename cannot contain newline characters.

In your last approach, you are doing the ls locally (because of the backticks), before the ssh is executed. You have to escape the backticks, so that they are "seen" by the remote shell.
